# Calling a function that is outside of a class from inside

Tags: interrupt, timers, class

I have an Arduino sketch with a timer interrupt class and would like to place the TIMER2Services() function in the TimerTwoTest.ino file for easy access. On compile I get a multiple definition of tmb2 error in the .ino TIMER2Services() function. I have tried all the variations I can think of but no luck. Is there a way to do this?

```
TimerTwoTest.cpp.o: In function `TIMER2Services()':
D:\Arduino157/TimerTwoTest.ino:41: multiple definition of `tmb2'
TimerTwo.cpp.o:C:\Users\...\build8577138580185682113.tmp/TimerTwo.cpp:10: first defined here
```

collect2.exe:

**TimerTwo.h:**

```
class Tmb2
{
  public:
  void initTIMER2(unsigned int Hz, unsigned int ulPeriod);
  void resetTIMER2(unsigned int Hz, unsigned int ulPeriod);
  TIMER2_TYPE getPeriodTIMER2(void);
  void activeTIMER2 (void);
  private:
}tmb2;
```

**TimerTwo.cpp:**

```
extern void TIMER2Services(void);

[this function is line 10 for the error]
void Tmb2::initTIMER2(unsigned int Hz, unsigned int ulPeriod){  //setperiod and enable interrupt
  if (Hz){
    ulPeriod = 1000/Hz;    //if Hz > 0 use frequency microseconds
  }
  Timer2.attachInterrupt(TIMER2Services).setPeriod(ulPeriod).start();
}
```

**TimerTwoTest.ino:**

```
volatile unsigned long burpCount = 0;

//This routine services the interrupt
void TIMER2Services(void){
  burpCount++;
}
```

Comment: Which file(s) are you including, and where? Also: it looks like you're using an external library: is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your definition of tmb2.  You're declaring the variable in the header file, and not the C(++) file.

Please try this:

**TimerTwo.h**

```
#ifndef __TIMER_TWO_H__
#define __TIMER_TWO_H__

extern void TIMER2Services(void);

class Tmb2
{
    public:
        void initTIMER2(unsigned int Hz, unsigned int ulPeriod);
        void resetTIMER2(unsigned int Hz, unsigned int ulPeriod);
        TIMER2_TYPE getPeriodTIMER2(void);
        void activeTIMER2 (void);
    private:
};

#endif // #ifndef __TIMER_TWO_H__
```

The #ifndef TIMER stuff saves you getting multiple definitions from header files if they're included more than once.  There's other ways to do this, but this is simple and well-known.

**TimerTwo.cpp**

```
#include "TimerTwo.h"

void Tmb2::initTIMER2(unsigned int Hz, unsigned int ulPeriod)
{  
    //setperiod and enable interrupt
    if (Hz)
    {
        ulPeriod = 1000/Hz;    //if Hz > 0 use frequency microseconds
    }
    Timer2.attachInterrupt(TIMER2Services).setPeriod(ulPeriod).start();
}
```

**TimerTwoTest.ino**

```
#include "TimerTwo.h"

Tmb2 tmb2;
volatile unsigned long burpCount = 0;

// This routine services the interrupt
void TIMER2Services(void)
{
    burpCount++;
}

void setup()
{
    tmb2.initTIMER2(blah1,blah2);
}
```

For the sake of neatness, I'd move TIMER2Services into class Tmb2 as a static function... if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't `TimerTwo tmb2;` be `Tmb2 tmb2;`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right Gerben.  I've just edited it

Comment: I would also re-think the closeness of the class name and instantiation name: Tmb2 looks very much like tmb2, and could lead to errors of mistaken identity. It's certainly a personal 'good practice' for me, but there are no rules for either opinions.